# Add Google AdMob in PhoneGap Project

Tags: android, admob, phonegap, phonegap-admob

I have been trying to add AdMob in my PhoneGap project for several days. But I could not find a way to show adds on my app. I have followed some tutorials, but nothing seems to be helpful. I was using Google-provided test ad units for Banner `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`. I was testing the app by building apk from [Adobe PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) and then running app by installing the apk in my Android Phone. This is what I did:

To add the AdMob plugin in my project:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-admob
```

And then in my index.js file

**Code #1**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        admob.setOptions({
            publisherId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111",
            isTesting: false,
            autoShowBanner: true,
        });
        admob.createBannerView();
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        if (parentElement != null) {
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        }
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

**Code #2**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        alert("device ready");
        app.adSetter();
    },
    adSetter: function(){
        alert(navigator.userAgent);
        var admobid = {};
        if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
            admobid = {
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
            };
        }
        if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
            adId:admobid.banner, 
            position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
            autoShow:true
        } );
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        if (parentElement != null) {
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        }
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

None of the above worked. What am I doing wrong?

What I need to do to add AdMob in my PhoneGap project and show adds in my app?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: did you put the test ad under the publisher id? looks so. as far as im aware, you need to still use your publisher id... and then the test id until u go prod

Comment: @soldforapp Sorry couldn't understand. Can you please explain more or give some references where I can learn about it?

Comment: Me also wanted to learn this but couldn't find.